# Personalizar MessageBox no C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Tenho o seguinte `MessageBox`

```
MessageBox.Show("Deseja iniciar a forma automática?", "Atenção", 
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
```

Consigo personalizar ele?

Em vez de ser os botões `YesNo`, colocar dois botões com `labels` personalizadas

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 6):

Isso não é possível, ele foi criado para fazer algo bem estrito mesmo. Esse é um caso onde você precisa criar seu próprio componente.

Para não deixar sem nenhuma referência tem [algo pronto no CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox), mas nunca usei e não sei se é bom. Talvez não te atenda, mas é uma base para você construir o seu.

Se nem isso servir então terá que construir como um formulário normal configurado adequadamente para ter semântica semelhante (provavelmente será modal).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa criar seu próprio `Window`, com um `Label` e dois `Buttons`

```
public partial class MeuMsgBox : Form
 {
        public MeuMsgBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent(); 
        }

        public DialogResult Resultado { get; private set; }

        public static DialogResult Mostrar(string mensagem, string textoSim, string textoNao)
        {
            var msgBox = new MeuMsgBox();
            msgBox.lblMensagem.Text = mensagem;
            msgBox.btnSim.Text = textoSim;
            msgBox.btnNao.Text = textoNao;
            msgBox.ShowDialog();
            return msgBox.Resultado;
        }

        private void btnSim_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Resultado = DialogResult.Yes;
            Close();
        }

        private void btnNao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Resultado = DialogResult.No;
            Close();
        }
}
```

Utilização:

```
DialogResult resultado = MeuMsgBox.Mostrar("Minha pergunta?", "Clique em Sim", "Clique em não");
```

Cabe a você caprichar no layout para ficar bonito.